# If an adverbial is at the beginning of a subordinate clause, should I separate it both from the subordinating conjunction and the rest of the clause?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

For example, here's a sentence, "What was new was that(,) now(,) the party abstained from a vote" (you can additionally comment on the "was was" structure, if you wish; I don't see anything wrong with it). What should I do with the commas?

Comment: Whatever you want to do with them. Use commas only if the meaning of the sentence can be conveyed if *now* is removed. In short, if what you want to convey could be conveyed with *(now)*, then use commas. Otherwise, don't. Using commas makes *now* parenthetical and syntactically nonrestrictive.

Comment: Should I put a comma on both sides of it or only after an adverbial but not between the preposition and the adverbial?

Comment: It has nothing to do with anything being adverbial. It's purely a matter of if *now* is essential to the meaning you're trying to convey or if it's just optional and additional. I can't tell you if *now* is essential or not—only you can say that, based on what you mean to say.

Comment: Is it even an OPTION to put a comma only AFTER the conjunction but NOT BEFORE it? Tell me that, please

Comment: Sure. That would make the phrase that follows it an appositive. It would be clarifying what *that* was. *What was new was **that** now. (The party abstained from a vote.)* Of course, *that* would no longer be functioning as a conjunction but as a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: So if I want to use it as a conjunction, I can either separate it at both sides or not put commas at all, is that correct?